# If I have a complex valued odd/even holomorphic function, can I say anything about parity of its real/imaginary part as $R^2$ functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=f(x_1,x_2)=f(x_1+i x_2)=u(x_1,x_2)+iv(x_1,x_2)$ be a holomorphic function, then by Cauchy-Riemann:
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}(x_1, x_2), \quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}(x_1, x_2)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2).$

If I'm not wrong it means that if $u$ is odd in $x_i$, $v$ must be even in $x_i$, right?

My question is: suppose $$f(-z)=-f(z),$$
then it must be true that $u(-x_1,-x_2)=-u(x_1,x_2),v(-x_1,-x_2)=-v(x_1,x_2)$. But,

can I say anything about $u(-x_1,x_2),v(-x_1,x_2),u(x_1,-x_2),v(x_1,-x_2)$?

EDIT:
From Ted Shifrin comment I realize that it should have to be a relation with the power series. Let's say:
$$f(z)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty c_i z^i.$$
as $$u=(f+\bar{f})/2=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty \frac{c_i z^i + \bar{c}_i \bar{z}^i}{2}$$
then if $c_i$ are reals $u(x_1,-x_2)=u(x_1,x_2)$.

Is it a sufficient condition to say $c_i$ are reals?

What should be the condition for $u(-x_1,x_2)=-u(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: No, why should you? Do you know the coefficients of the power series expansion at $0$ are real, imaginary, or anything else?

Comment: I see your point. But it should be some conditions in the opposite sense (if I have parity information on $u$ or $v$) Right?